# The method access$110(GameHandler) is undefined for the type GameHandler

Tags: java, bukkit

Okay, so I have an error that keeps bugging me and I don't know how to fix it.. So would be glad if u could help me with it. The error? Read the title. :P

```
public void run()
{
    if (GameHandler.this.timelimit < 0)
    {
        for (Player player : GameHandler.this.arena.getPlayersManager().getPlayersInArena())
        {
            GameHandler.this.arena.getPlayerHandler().leavePlayer(player, Messages.arenatimeout, "");
        }
            GameHandler.this.stopArena();
            return;
        }

        if (GameHandler.this.arena.getPlayersManager().getPlayersCount() == 0)
        {
            GameHandler.this.stopArena();
            return;
        }

        for (Player player : GameHandler.this.arena.getPlayersManager().getPlayersInArena())
        {
            Bars.setBar(player, Bars.playing, GameHandler.this.arena.getPlayersManager().getPlayersCount(), GameHandler.this.timelimit / 20, GameHandler.this.timelimit * 5 / GameHandler.this.arena.getStructureManager().getTimeLimit());

            GameHandler.this.handlePlayer(player);
        }
        GameHandler.access$110(GameHandler.this); //**Error is here. ("access$110")**
      }
```

Comment: Does `GameHandler` have a method `public static void access$110(GameHandler var);`? And if not, why are you calling it?  And what do you expect that line to do?

Comment: Did you use adecompiler for this code? Normally access methods are inserted during compilation and cannot be called explicitly.

Comment: I've fixed it, and no I did not use a decompiler. It was a mistake in another part of the project. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: why have a dollar sign in a method name? that just feels wrong

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that you code wasn't compiled correctly.  The access$xxx methods are generated by the compiler to allow it to access private members of other classes which the JVM doesn't actually support.

To get this class to compile if you decompiled it, you have to recompile all the classes which came from the same file, not just one as it is more than likely different classes were assign different accessor methods.